# How to parse title from sites using python?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

I am new to python and cannot understand how to implement the following task.
There is a txt file with domains (about 10,000 domains) stored in upper case. Necessary:
 - transfer domain addresses to lower case
 - add the string 'http: //' at the beginning of the domain so that the domain is then inserted into requests
 - make a loop so that the parser collects the title from each domain (site)
 - write everything to a file table with two fields | site url | site title |

that's what happened:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

f = open(r'file.txt','r+')
a=[]
for i in f:
    a.append(i.lower().replace('\n',''))
    a[-1]='http://'+a[-1]
f.close()
title_list=[]
for url in a:
    try:
        r=requests.get(url)
        page=bs(r.content,'html.parser')
        title=page.find('title')
        title_list.append(url)
        title_list.append(title.text.replace('\n',''))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

print(title_list)
```

I don’t know how to implement server error checking

Comment: sounds to me like the task is broken down for you, so just do a little research. 1) read in a txt file. 2) read it (possibly line by line), and convert to lower case 3) add `'http://'` to the beginning of that string, 4) feed that string into requests to get the html 5) pull out the title of the html it receives; 5) write that to a table of 2 columns. Start with being able to do #1

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

file = open('urllist.txt', 'r')
urlList = file.readlines()
file.close()

titles = []

for url in urlList:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://' + url.lower()))
    titles.append(soup.title.string)
```

#### Note:

- 'urllist.txt' is the file containing URLs
- titles will contain the list of website titles

Hope this helps :)